# Is there a concurrent GC in Android?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, jvm

I came across this guide about [Concurrent Mark Sweep (CMS) Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html) in JVM, and I wonder if something similar is available in Android or not?

And if it's even considered a good idea in Android since a concurrent GC uses additional CPU power to perform?

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/gc-debug

Comment: FYI: Android doesn't have a JVM.

Comment: @Andreas yes, Android has its own Runtime, that's why i asked if it has something similar